# Are there step by step tutorials for beginners on things like setting up bluetooth or SSH?

Tags: setup, tutorial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bluetooth keyboard/mouse for surfing internet on my TV](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/797/bluetooth-keyboard-mouse-for-surfing-internet-on-my-tv)

Is there a step by step for using a bluetooth keyboard and mouse with RasPi? Or SSH?

I've seen the forum posts regarding using BT, and they are not complete enough for someone like me, who is very new to Linux. They seem to assume some (apparently basic) knowledge I don't have (or I'm missing something through my own ignorance.)

I would hope to see more direct and detailed tutorials for folks like me. Can anyone point me in the right direction for something like that?