# A2DP stereo audio over bluetooth

Tags: raspbian, audio, bluetooth

Using the instructions in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-can-i-use-a-bluetooth-mouse-and-keyboard/#938) I was able to get Bluetooth working with a small Asus branded USB receiver. I was able to see other Bluetooth devices in the area, but whenever I put my Motorola S10 headset in discoverable mode and ran the `hcitool scan` command, it would freeze up for a moment and then return with the error `Inquiry failed: Connection timed out`

I am guessing it is probably just missing the required bits to enable the A2DP and/or Headset profiles that the S10 is reporting back as supporting. Is there a package I can just `apt-get` and enjoy? For what it is worth, I installed bluetooth, bluez-utils and blueman through apt-get.

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
...
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3005 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3011 Bluetooth

# hcitool scan
Scanning ...
Inquiry failed: Connection timed out
```

Comment: You should try connecting the USB Bluetoorh dongle through a powered USB HUB. It might be a power issue.

Comment: I had a same problem, because I was using a powered USB HUB, plugging it in normally solved my problems. Maybe try that :)

Comment: Have you solved this? We're trying to clean up the site and this one has been dead for a while.

Comment: I haven't tried a powered hub (don't have one) but I did use a higher output (1A) 5V adapter and it seems to work. I wouldn't say the question is _answered_ but available current does seem to be at to root of the issue.

Comment: Yeah, "get a stable high-current power supply instead of any old charger adapter you have lying around" seems to be the #1 solution to a lot of RasPi problems.

Comment: Goyuix - you might want to put that as _an_ answer, though.

Comment: I had a similar issue a while ago and then I got a 5v 2A micro-usb power supply and haven't ever had an issue since. They're like $15.00on Amazon! I'm currently running a 2TB USB 3.0 external hard drive, HDMI, audio, ethernet, and of coarse the Raspberry Pi off of it.

Comment: I've put an inquiry in to Qualcomm about the power needs of the AR3011 chipset in different modes.  We'll see if that yields any specific fruit.

Answer (score 1):

Although not officially considered "answered" by the OP, he *did* find a temporary solution, which I believe merits at least a stand-in answer until he finds a full solution. You can read the comment that I believe merits this stand-in [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/a2dp-stereo-audio-over-bluetooth#comment17313_1647).

This answer can be removed as soon as the OP decides that he has completely solved the issue.