# Connecting an Apple mouse and keyboard to Model B+

Tags: hardware

I have been given a new Model B+ for Fathers Day. I have connected the computer but my keyboard/mouse that I use with my Mac computer will not work with the PI
Do I need a new keyboard/mouse to use with the PI?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/797/how-can-i-use-a-bluetooth-mouse-and-keyboard can you try to follow the instructions at this link, it should work for you.

Comment: If you can't get that to happen, any relatively normal generic USB keyboard, wired or wireless, should work with no problems.   Around here you can find them easily at big box or electronics stores for $10-15 USD.  Just avoid anything that looks weird or targets gamers, these may require drivers that the manufacturer does not provide for linux.